# Multi Level Bash Completion using existing completion functions?

Tags: bash, bash-completion

I created a simple bash function : http://shr.im/ionyse-notify

I would like to add a little completion file.

I found two interesting functions :

- _known_hosts
- _user_at_host

How can I say that for the first argument, it should complete using _known_hosts and for the second using _user_at_host

```
#!/bin/bash

_send-msg_complete()
{
  local cur prev

  COMPREPLY=()
  cur=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}
  prev=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD-1]}

  if [ $COMP_CWORD -eq 1 ]; then
      COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -F _known_hosts -- $cur) )
  elif [ $COMP_CWORD -eq 2 ]; then
      COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -F _user_at_host -- $cur) )
  fi

  return 0
} &&

complete -F _send-msg_complete send-msg
```

Here is what I have, but it doesn't work. What's wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, it is quite simple :

```
#!/bin/bash

_send-msg_complete()
{
  local cur prev

  COMPREPLY=()
  cur=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}
  prev=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD-1]}

  if [ $COMP_CWORD -eq 1 ]; then
      _known_hosts
  elif [ $COMP_CWORD -eq 2 ]; then
      _user_at_host
  fi

  return 0
} &&

complete -F _send-msg_complete send-msg
```